# Delphi 7: No second parameter in TStrings.SaveToFile() method

Tags: unicode, delphi-7

I need to make changes to an old legacy project in Delphi 7.

I need to save a `TStringList` to a file with Unicode encoding. All resources I have found describe a second parameter for specifying an encoding in the `SaveToFile()`/`LoadFromFile()` methods, but there is no such parameter in Delphi 7. It was probably added in later versions.

How can I save UTF-8 text to a file (`.csv`) in Delphi 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for was introduced in Delphi 2009, when Delphi's `String` type migrated from `AnsiString` to `UnicodeString`.

Prior to Delphi 2009, you will have to encode the `TStringList` entries to UTF-8 yourself. You can put UTF-8 data in an `AnsiString` (`UTF8String` in those versions was just an alias for `AnsiString`), and `TStringList` will save the data as-is.

However, you may be tempted to use the RTL's `UTF8Encode()` function, but know that prior to Delphi 2009 it doesn't support Unicode codepoints above `U+FFFF`.  If you need to handle codepoints that high, you will have to use Microsoft's [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) function instead.